# gitlab disfunctions after editing git-data

Tags: git, gitlab

I was trying to edit a repo in git-data/repositories (on my remote server) to edit a project name.
After that some troubleshootings appears on my gitlab.
I set a backup folder to cancel my modifications.
After that some repositories in my gitlab are no more working from gitlab (404 when i select the a repo), some other repositories appears empty. But these projects are present and I can clone, pull, commit and push from these repo.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe the gitlab logs you help you see why you have 404?

Comment: gitlab logs said only that repo not found :s

Comment: Is there a reason why you have edited the repo directly and used the function in the GUI? You get probably the error because the project name in DB fit no longer the repo. In my opinion the best way would be to roll back aka rename the repo back to its old name and then use the GUI function.

Comment: I have edited directly the repo because when i was renaming or deleting a repo, it still on server. I did a backup before of repos and i restore it but still disfunctions.